# How to choose the right spring-beans namespace version

Tags: spring, spring-security

What will be the problem if I come to use Spring-beans namespace 3.0 and Spring security namespace version 3.2 ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There will be no problem with the namespaces.

The only concern is that, the underlying frameworks (Spring and Spring Security) must been compatible.

In some cases it is wise to use the namespace that matches the underlying framework versions. But in most cases newer frameworks can handle older namespaces

- the new Spring versions are almost compatible to namespace 3.0
- in Spring Security they often invented new features so sometimes you need the matching namespace to configure the required features))

And Spring Security this is from Spring Security 3.2 Reference:

> Spring Security builds against Spring Framework 3.2.13.RELEASE, but is
>   also tested against Spring Framework 4.1.6.RELEASE. This means you can
>   use Spring Security 3.2.10.CI-SNAPSHOT with Spring Framework
>   4.1.6.RELEASE. The problem that many users will have is that Spring Security’s transitive dependencies resolve Spring Framework
>   3.2.13.RELEASE causing all sorts of strange classpath problems.

Comment: thanks for your replay, good answer ! another thing that i would to know is how spring does the parsing of the configuration file, that's means if spring use the same Parsing API to process both the config file with namespace 3.0 and 3.2 ? Thanks

Comment: @user2602584 Spring has a concept of Namespacehandlers and BeanDefinition parsers, (it is a quite old concept: since Spring 2.0), you can use them to extend spring xml with custom namespaces. ("42. Extensible XML authoring" http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xml-custom.html, Chapter "Appendix E. Extensible XML authoring" in older Reference Guides)  And Spring use the same mechanism by its own: so have a look at the spring-beans.jar\META-INF files and you will see that spring use the same Handler for the different versions -> it is compatibel

Comment: @user2602584: the parsing form spring (beans) and spring-security is separated (Handlers are complete different). But of course they use the same underlying infrastructure (spring). So for Spring security 3.2 you need at least Spring 3.2 framework. But you can use older namespaces for Spring, for example 3.0